# How to get some values with a loop from Hashes of hashes in Perl

Tags: perl, configuration-files

I have a config.file to do some tests and i would like to get some values from this one also.

Here my config.file:

```
my $folder = 'E:\FOLDER\Test\WEB';
{
       license => [ 'kit-licence.zip',
                    'kit-work.zip'
                   ],
       programs => [
             #template society =>\%program_work
             'VIKTOR DESCRIPTION PRODUCT' => { 
                    name => 'VIKTOR ', 
                    parameters => [
                           Count_id                           => '06 (Viktor)',
                           Birth_date                    => '1995-04-30',
                           Marriage_date              => '2014-05-26',
                           Divorce_date               => '2015-03-30',
                           Activities_folder               => $folder.'\VIKTOR\independent worker',
                           Activities_format               => 'Enterprise Format (V35)',
                           Description_File_from       => $folder.'\VIKTOR\FILE\description.xlm',

                    ] 
             },

             'OLIVER NEW OBJECT' => {   
                    name => 'OLIVER ', 
                    parameters => [
                           Count_id                           => '06 (oliver)',
                           Birth_date                    => '1990-04-30',
                           Marriage_date              => '2011-03-26',
                           Divorce_date               => '2014-01-30',
                           Activities_folder               => $folder.'\OLIVER\independent worker',
                           Activities_format               => 'Enterprise Format (V35)',
                           Description_File_from       => $folder.'\OLIVER\FILE\description.xlm',

                    ] 
             }, 
       ]
};
```

My file test is following:

```
#test.pl
use Modern::Perl;
my $config = do 'work.conf';
use Data::Dumper;
say Dumper( $config );
```

To get parameters in Programs for Viktor for example, I can do this:

```
 %programs = @{ $config->{programs} };
    for my $prog (values %programs) {
      my %param = @{ $prog->{parameters} };
      for my $name (sort keys %param){
       print $name, ': ', $param{$name},"\n";
      }
    }
```

But in my case, I want to be able to get parameters for every user. Here it's just for Viktor. I would like to get them for Oliver or for another user. For that, and to differentiate all users,  I have to use the "template society" which is the name to differentiate every user. For example, for Viktor, it's: "VIKTOR DESCRIPTION PRODUCT". For Oliver: "OLIVER NEW OBJECT".

How can I do that?

Same thing for "License":

```
 license => [ 'kit-licence.zip',
               'kit-work.zip'
                   ],
       programs => [..
```

I would like to get the license by name of each one. For example, 'kit-license.zip'.

And not by "hard coding" like that:

```
use File::Spec::Functions qw/catfile/;
my $filename = catfile($::svn, ${$config->{license}}[0]);
my $filename1 = catfile($::svn, ${$config->{license}}[1]);
```

Perhaps in a loop, but I didn't find.

PS: Don't ask me why they are all divorced. I really don't know.

Comment: I wouldn't wonder about the divorced status, but rather about why this data structure is so strange.

Answer (score 2):

You're already doing a good job converting those array refs into hashes. But the `values` is making your life hard. You need the key and the value at the same time. You can use [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) to do that.

```
my %programs = @{ $config->{programs} };
while (my ($template_society, $value) = each %programs ) {
    my %param = @{ $value->{parameters} };
    print "$template_society\n";
    for my $name ( sort keys %param ) {
        print "\t", $name, ': ', $param{$name}, "\n";
    }
}
```

This will produce the following output:

```
VIKTOR DESCRIPTION PRODUCT
    Activities_folder: \VIKTOR\independent worker
    Activities_format: Enterprise Format (V35)
    Birth_date: 1995-04-30
    Count_id: 06 (Viktor)
    Description_File_from: \VIKTOR\FILE\description.xlm
    Divorce_date: 2015-03-30
    Marriage_date: 2014-05-26
OLIVER NEW OBJECT
    Activities_folder: \OLIVER\independent worker
    Activities_format: Enterprise Format (V35)
    Birth_date: 1990-04-30
    Count_id: 06 (oliver)
    Description_File_from: \OLIVER\FILE\description.xlm
    Divorce_date: 2014-01-30
    Marriage_date: 2011-03-26
```

The `each` built-in returns both the key and the value of a hash per iteration, and `undef` once it's done. That's why you need to put it in a `while` loop.

If you don't like the `each` approach, you can also use `keys` instead of `values` to get the keys (`$template_society`) and use that to look up the appropriate value.

```
my %programs = @{ $config->{programs} };
foreach my $template_society (keys %programs ) {
    my %param = @{ $programs{$template_society}->{parameters} };
    print "$template_society\n";
    for my $name ( sort keys %param ) {
        print "\t", $name, ': ', $param{$name}, "\n";
    }
}
```

This will give you the same output.

---

To get all your licence paths you need to store them in an array and use a loop to process your array ref into that array. The easiest and most concise way to do that is using [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html).

```
my @licences = map { catfile($::svn, $_ ) } @{ $config->{license} };
```

It's like a `foreach` loop, just shorter. The BLOCK is basically a function that gets the current iteration item in `$_`. It's essentially the same as the following, just more perlish.

```
my @licences;
foreach my $licence (@{ $config->{license} } ) {
    push @licences, catfile($::svn, $licence );
}
```

**Do not** attempt to create variables like `$foo1`, `$foo2` and so on dynamically. That will not work. [See this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150210001429/http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html)<sup>1</sup> for an explanation why.

---

Finally a word on `$::svn`: if you are in a package, you should put your code into a function and accept `$svn` as an argument. Working with globals or package variables from different packages is tricky and messy and you will at some point shoot yourself in the foot with it.

<sup>1: The normal document is currently broken, so I used archive.org to get it</sup>

Comment: Thanks @simbabque . Your approach is pretty good. I will take the time to see and understand that. Have you got any idea for second part of my post, concerning "license". Thanks in advance !

Comment: @Chaoui05 I didn't understand that part at first. But I think I got it now. You need to use an array to store the names. I'll update.

Comment: Thanks ! So i'am waiting your solution with curiosity

Comment: Btw, you don't need to ping me with `@simbabque` on my own posts. You get notified about every comment on your own post anyway. [See this meta.se post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/202151). :)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply again ! it's very well explained. Yes , i thought it but it was to be sure ^^ . Anyway , thanks , that's a thing i appreciate in Perl community , the community :)

Comment: Oups. Just a last precision. If i want , in "license" case,  to recover each license in a variable, how can i do with your two approachs ? Promise , it's the last thing !

Comment: @Chaoui05 I don't understand the question. If you mean you want to put each one into a separate variable, then the answer is **don't do it**. Read the document I linked above.